# MySQL: Selecting data from MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, linked-server

How do I select data from a MS SQL Server from MySQL? We have a system of linked server in SQL Server. I have also heard that you can do a linked server to Mysql from sql server. But I want to know the reverse.

The mssql server is what we use mainly for production. So one main reason we'd want to do this is simply to get the exact mssql server's time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it will be possible, reverse is possible with only .Net scripting support. However, you may setup a time synchronization mechanism between two servers.